# What exactly is $_SERVER['URL'] in php?

Tags: php

I have to service a small intranet web-application which is written in php. And there is the predefined variable $_SERVER['URL'] in use. I cannot find this in the php documentation and I cannot remember that I have seen this before. And in my test environment (php 5.4.16) this parameter doesn't exist. Is this an old deprecated parameter?

Comment: $_SERVER is an array, therefore anyone can add / remove parameters manually. I personally can't recall that there ever existed key 'URL', so I assume that someone who used to work on your app created that key  via underlying web server or manually via PHP code.

Comment: check this out to get the `URL` (if you need it): [GET URL](http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/27.html)

Comment: The amount of people on SO who aren't reading nor using their brain is surprisingly hard. I just don't understand why are there so many people telling this guy to check out the docs when he **says he didn't find anything about URL key in the docs**. This is a perfectly valid question, not every key found in $_SERVER has to be documented, as @YourCommonSense answered. People wondering why they got -1 in their answers - well, you guys just didn't read, and that's why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$_SERVER` contains values from various sources, including server environment variables. So, most likely this variable is set by the host server as an ENV variable and PHP has nothing to do with it.

Comment: I hoped that there is more information, but thanks a lot anyway. I've now analysed the code and just replaced the variable. I hope the new one is equal to the old. best thanks again.

Comment: Well, at least you have the certain answer to your question - why id $_SERVER['URL'] in php? - from server environment. It's just impossible to tell more. as a proof, ypu can run phpinfo() and see env variables - I am sure you will find your URL there

Comment: On my IIS server with PHP 8.1.4, `URL` is in `$_SERVER` but **not** in the `Environment` section of `phpinfo()`.  Almost 10 years later and I can't seem to find info about this...

Comment: @Goozak try IIS documentation, you may have some luck there

Comment: Ah!  Indeed, it is mentioned in [IIS Server Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/web-dev-reference/server-variables) : "The base portion of the URL without any querystring information.".

Answer (score -4):

URL doesn't seem to be supported on the PHP Manual pages, but this might be what you're after...

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

That should give you the URI that the client used when making the request - but these Server variables are not guarunteed to be implemented on servers - check the servers you will be deploying to before using this approach.

Comment: Downvoting is fine - but perhaps you might enlighten us as to why?

Comment: Because 1) you didn't answer the question, 2) didn't read what the author said 3) didn't *understand* what he asked and 4) came to the wrong conclusion about what someone "meant". By all standards of logic, what you wrote is not an answer, and therefore isn't useful to answer the original question. And since I got the liberty to mark  something not useful with -1, you got it.